# How do I enable the one-handed keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, ios

I would like to enable a different keyboard layout for one-handed use. I know it's possible, since it was mentioned at WWDC 2017, but how do I do it?

Settings doesn’t have an option to enable a one-handed keyboard:

[image]

In the Keyboards list, there is no one-handed keyboard either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Keyboard switching icon

**Hold down on the keyboard switching icon (usually a globe or smiling face) and on the last menu item, pick the right or left option.** Note that this only works when more than one keyboard is enabled because the keyboard switching icon only shows when needed.

[image: Picker for keyboard layouts]

The 3 keyboard icons are for enabling the one-handed layout.

If you pick the left option, you'll be able to use the keyboard with only your left hand, and the same is true with the right option. The center option makes the keyboard two-handed again.

[image: Table of keyboard options]

### Settings app

In the Keyboard settings (Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> One Handed Keyboard), you can select between the keyboards.

This method works regardless of how many keyboards you’ve enabled.

---

Here's an example of the right-handed keyboard:

[image: Right-handed keyboard]

Comment: On supported devices only...

Answer (score -1):

You have to turn off zoomed view in display and brightness settings. Then the one hand keyboard option will show up.

Comment: This is the same solution as provided in [an earlier answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295701/37797)?